# Punctuate number at thousands XPages - converter

Tags: xpages, converters, xpages-ssjs

Have you any idea what pattern I have to insert into converter for the subject request?

And can I execute converter when Input the text so that the user can see in realtime the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dijit.form.NumberTextBox` for this purpose. It by default punctuates after every 3 digits.

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" dojoType="dijit.form.NumberTextBox"></xp:inputText>
```

Make sure you add the Dojo module in your resources of XPage.

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.NumberTextBox"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>
```

If you have extension library then you can simply use Dojo Number Text Box.

```
<xe:djNumberTextBox id="djNumberTextBox1"></xe:djNumberTextBox>
```

Comment: Tnx work but only when you exit from the focus of the field. I need to work in raltime when the user digit every value